# Update one part of state when another part of state get changed in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

For example in a shopping cart i can update the cart state when a product is added to cart but how can i update the product state at the same time.

I have used the combineReducers to combine both the cart and product reducers.

Edit: I have posted the answer below, Please check it.

Comment: you could just dispatch two actions, one targeting cart reducer and the other targeting product reducer.

Comment: You have to disaptch 2 actions.

Comment: Can't you simply handle the same action in the two reducers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have figure out the answer,  we can do this as mentioned below.

```
onClick={() => {
         addToCart(product.id, product.name, product.price);    
         updateProductList(product.id)
}}
```

This is es6 way of calling two function on a single click, so we can manage two different states simultaneously. I have called this in presentation component.
we can create the respective action & reducers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by composing reducers. Use two different reducers. Always think of different reducer for changing different part of the state. That will make state changes more clean. So one way of achieving this is send the first action for altering the cart state. Once that is success use componentWillReceiveProps to check if the state is upadated for cart. If so send the other action for product.

Comment: Thanks for replying. It would be helpful if you provide some reference or code.